# App Config file - Ensure Custom Configuration Structure

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have a library that reads from a custom section in app.config

Is there a proper way to ensure that when this library is used in a project, it creates the "skeleton" of its custom section if it's not provided?

I want to ensure that whenever this get's used, by whomever, they will be able to understand what they have access to configure without looking inside the library.

EDIT: In order to be more specific, here is an example app config with some explanation of what I'm trying to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="CustomSection" type="Test.CustomSection, CustomSection"/>
    </configSections>
    <CustomSection SettingOne="My Setting"/>
</configuration>
```

That is an example of a section I would have created, knowing that SettingOne is a setting that works, and knowing about CustomSection and all of that.  What I would like to do, is have my CustomSection.dll file, when included and used in a project, update a config file to make sure CustomSection is available with some default settings.

The result I would like to be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section .... >
        <section .... >
        <!-- Custom Section below added -->
        <section name="CustomSection" type="Test.CustomSection, CustomSection"/>
    </configSections>
    <!-- Settings below also added -->
    <CustomSection SettingOne="DEFAULT"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customize the following app.config in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354653/customize-the-following-app-config-in-c)

Comment: did you read the answers in the linked question?

Comment: @jgauffin Thanks for the link, but I'm already able to setup the config file, I don't think that article has the info I'm looking for.  I've updated my post to be more specific.  I can already read from the file, and the custom sections are working fine.  I want to write default information to the file when the custom section isn't present.  And I'd like to do that in every project that references my dll.  I did read the link but I'll take another look in case I missed something.

Comment: You want to be able to force the format of the custom config section and also get intelli sense. The tool in the linked question can generate exactly that for you.

Comment: I'm looking to do this without the use of a tool.

Comment: Your program should be doing this when it creates the custom section within the configuration file.  Of course the simplest way around this problem is to allow the user to configure the application while the program is creating the section itself.